# RabbitMQ - Stop publishing and subscribing

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

We have a system which publishes messages to the RabbitMQ and subscribes from it and each of this is done as Task in C#.
Is there any way I could stop the publish and subscribe when some matching criteria is found. 
Lets say, for example i got an exception while publishing a particular message (just hypothetical), so now i want to stop publishing to the queue and also consumers from consuming from the same queue.
Is there any way this could be achieved?
We have a control bus implementation and Tasks based one.
Every message is published via different Tasks.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Plenty of ways to do that; this feels too broad.

Comment: Doesn't seem to me like that's the proper place for that, you should manage your connections to RabbitMQ in order to avoid consuming the messages I guess

Comment: I want to stop the entire process. not just consumption of messages. The publishing should also be stopped and publishing happens in separate Tasks.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Could you elaborate on the methods. I really can't get anything. I mean, the Task I want to cancel was created in another class and so I cannot access its CancellationToken and so I cannot find a way to stop the task.

Comment: You can't just pass the cancellation token in? Call a method on the parent class that then uses the token? Thats what I mean by this being too broad. It seems like a program architecture question, and at the very least we haven't seen yours or why it is causing problems.

Comment: I got the task cancelled, which was done using CancellationToken. My question was how to stop the publishers and subscribers corresponding to the task that was just cancelled.